# Hibernate performance improvement for simple query and huge data

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate

There are many articles regarding Hibernate performance improvements, but I am still not able to crack this issue.

1. We are currently generating a report (CSV) with a huge number of records (~50k records).
2. First the hibernate fetches the data and then Java code creates CSV file using the fetched data.
3. The query is done on only 1 table, with 4 to 5 `where` conditions and a couple of `order by` columns. There are no joins, no subqueries, nothing. For instance, the generated query would look like this: `select col1, col2, col3,.. col20 from table_name where condition1 and condition2 and condition3`.
4. Table is indexed properly as per the required columns.
5. The data is generated everytime before exporting. Caching is not applicable.
6. Another point to note is that the Java entity mapped to the database table has around 70 fields since the table is having same number of columns.

Currently, it takes around 3 to 4 minutes to only fetch and return 50k records.
That means, the following code takes about 3-4 mins.

```
final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(EntityName.class);
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("property1").asc().ignoreCase());
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("property2").asc().ignoreCase());
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("condition1", condition1value));
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("condition2", condition2value));
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("condition2", condition3value));
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("condition4", condition4value));
return findByCriteria(criteria);
```

As mentioned earlier, I have referred to multiple references online, also tried using `Spring JDBCTemplate` as well.

Is there anything that I can do here to improve the time to fetch the data?

Comment: Don't read everything and then create the CSV. Stream the result directly to CSV. You can do this with the `JdbcTemplate` and a `RowCallbackHandler` (note NOT a `RowMapper`) which directly streams the row to a CSV file. Basically what you want is not load everything into memory first and then do the processing (that will aso eventually not work anymore due to huge memory usage).

Comment: How long take a native query over console?

Comment: @M.Deinum I can try that. Is there anything I can refer to?

Comment: @dit Takes almost the same time, or probably 15 to 20 seconds lesser.

Comment: @PramodKarandikar If you can't come up with a native query which is performant, how do you expect Hibernate to somehow better that?

Comment: Comparing the query execution and the execution of hibernate isn't fair. As hibernate also creates an object per row. So it creates 50000 (at least) objects (and probably 70 more per object so at least 3500000 objects, depending on the graph it can be even more). Creating those objects takes time.

Comment: @asa As M. Deinum pointed out, it's not fair to compare the native query and Hibernate query since Hibernate has to map the data to the corresponding java class. And also, the query is quite straightforward as mentioned the question. There's nothing that I can do to tune the query as such.

Comment: @M.Deinum As suggested by you, I tried a basic implementation of `RowCallbackHandler`. I agree that it would decrease memory footprint, however, it's solving the issue with the fetch time. Because even if I read the data first and then create a CSV, the CSV creation process alone takes hardly 5-7 seconds for 50k records.

Comment: It isn't about reducing the footprint it is about avoiding th overheard of creating intermediate objects, You can stream the result directly to the csv you don't need nor should first create a list of objects.

Comment: I agree. My point was it's still not reducing the time taken :)

Answer (score 0):

The time to fetch is probably not due to how you use hibernate, but more probably how the database is setup. Create an index for the columns you use in your database and the performance (of the fetching of the data) will be improved.

Comment: Yes, we do have the index on those columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your application setup such that you can cache specific Model instances (i.e. Entities), you can improve performance in that way. For example, you need to do something with a list of "Dog"s. If you know that you need to simply use the initially fetched list once, you can just cache the resultset and keep using it. This of course, involves some other configuration so that you can refetch the list if necessary. I use a proprietary ORM (not Hibernate) and model framework (not SPring), but it's more to do with the framework rather than ORM layer. If Spring has a way to do such caching, you might be able to use that.

Comment: I have edited my question, the data is generated every time for exporting. It's a live data export.